# Can you put mean and sd statistics in seperate columns instead of Mean(SD) with tbl_summary tables?

Tags: r, gtsummary

As the title says, I have data from various variables seperated for 2 experimental group.
I created a table with the tbl_summary function from the gtsummary package.
With the

```
statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd}, {min}-{max})")
```

code I can display the relevant information in a single column, however i want to have mean, sd and min-max in seperate columns with the experimental groups as spanners above.

I would be very thankful for any advice!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The package wasn't written to create tables like this per se. But it is possible. Example below!

```r
library(gtsummary)
#> #Uighur
library(tidyverse)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.4.0'

sd_gts <- function(data, variable, ...) {
  sd(data[[variable]], na.rm = TRUE)
}

tbl <- 
  trial %>%
  select(trt, age, marker) %>%
  tbl_strata(
    strata = trt, 
    ~.x %>%
      tbl_summary(
        statistic = all_continuous() ~ "{mean}",
        missing = "no"
      ) %>%
      modify_footnote(all_stat_cols() ~ NA) %>%
      add_stat(fns = all_continuous() ~ sd_gts) %>%
      modify_fmt_fun(list(add_stat_1 ~ partial(style_number, digits = 2))) %>%
      modify_header(list(stat_0 ~ "**Mean**",
                         add_stat_1 ~ "**SD**"))
  )
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2021-04-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>